Is this a misinstalled ducted hood and what to do about it?
I just moved in, know nothing about kitchens but bought it since it belonged to the previous tenant.
This doesn't look right though. There are no holes on the wall where the vent could connect to. Would it be fine to just not use the ventilation, or is there some sort of filter I could put on the open end to at least not have all the residue on top of the cabinet? Or any other suggestion that might not cost a lot?
It's an induction stove so I'm mostly concerned about moisture and an ugly fatty mess.


Edit: https://imgur.com/a/Gs3liZd picture of where to pipe connects to the hood

Where does the pipe leading of to the left in your 2nd pic go to?

Nowhere really, it's not connected to anything.

There is probably a filter of some sort in the lower unit. You do need to have some good ventilation over a stove/cooking surface. The installation was just never finished by the previous tenant. The existing duct should be extended up and through the ceiling, into the attic and through a roof vent or soffit vent. If there's no attic, then through an exterior wall.

https://imgur.com/a/Gs3liZd this is where the pipe connects to the hood, could a filter go there? There's no way out of the wall or ceiling and I'm assuming it'd be rather expensive to have someone make a hole somewhere to connect it outside. Thank you for your reply.

@Fit-Grapefruit  Look underneath the hood. There should be a filter there.  You can treat this as a ductless hood. Put a 90 degree bend at the top of the vertical duct and add a register.  You could put a filter there but it's better  to put it before the blower to keep the blower clean from grease.

@JACK if there's a filter, why'd the installer bother putting up this ducting?

@Huesmann  There's usually a filter right under the hood before the blower  with easy access in all hoods I've seen.  My guess is that the installer started adding the duct as instructed but then decided it was too difficult or impossible to get to the outside.

@Huesmann (and Jack) ducted hoods normally just have a grease filter (these days often based on a metal mesh that can be put in a dishwasher).  It should be straightforward to open it up from underneath, but a dumb/tricky design wouldn't surprise me.  Recirculating hoods tend to have odour filters as well (carbon) and the ones I've used have had better grease filters.  Better to fit a proper recirculating hood than to bodge this one, if you can't fit this properly.  Though in most places as a tenant there's little you can do.
